# webpack and react jsx - hot loading not working with docker container

Tags: docker, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Changed to: hot loading does not work in docker and it looks like it is a docker issue.

Following this: [React with webpack](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/) or this [React hot loader](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/) on local host machine they work fine and to me, they work the same - still I dont get why you would install [React hot loader](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/)?

But running it in a container, updating/"hot loading" does not work in any of them. So this might be a question a docker expert?

Comment: how does your webpack.config look and are you using a vm or something like vagrant?

Comment: Updated the question incl. web pack.config & package.son: I am running this in a container.

Comment: You do need to configure `react-hot-loader`  to use hot loading with React components. See http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/.

Comment: React or just for jsx files? See update.

Comment: you are not including the jsx-loader in your webpack.config you need to add it loaders  `babel|jsx` , thats the source of the error you included above

Comment: Changed the question, it became more and more complex. I did try with the jsx-loader and it works fine on local host machine. See updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I have not worked with docker all that much, although I ran into the same issue using vagrant - in my case it was an issue with the shared folders between the guest and host machines - I ended up using something called rsync to remedy the issue - perhaps there is a docker equivalent?

Comment: Yep, I might end up doing something like rsync. Thanks

Comment: I have this same problem,
 did you find a solution?

Comment: Just added a workaround as a solution.

Comment: When you say hot loading doesn't work, what do you mean?

Are you talking about file watching not working?

Or do you mean it is not hot loading?

Is it connecting to the socket.io correctly? (as in, do you see any errors when opening up the developer console?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [described on GitHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/143#issuecomment-139705511), you can do this:

```
watchOptions: {
    poll: true
}
```

Or, in the `package.json`, instead of `--watch` do `--watch --watch-poll`.

Comment: adding `--watch --watch-poll` worked for me. Live reloading worked on Ubuntu without this flag but using this flag made it work on Windows too. To provide more details, I was using Docker to work with from Windows [Haven't tried to work on Windows directly]

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a proper file watching solution on a mac with Docker, check out [docker-osx-dev](https://github.com/brikis98/docker-osx-dev). It uses boot2docker behind the scenes, but adds rsync support. I tried it and it works great for file changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround; I have a reverse proxy(nginx) running in a container. The proxy forwards back to my main host computer(a Mac) on a port. This gives me hot loading and most important, I have no issues with cross domain as I have my database running in yet another container.

Comment: Hi @chris-g, can you elaborate a little more on your solution? Can't get Hot Module Replacement to run. It's almost a year later, how do u handle this issue today?

Comment: I am still using the same solution. Do you know how to use nginx and reverse proxy?

Comment: I know a little about it, used php-fpm in one container and nginx in another to serve the incoming requests. nginx was used as a reverse-proxy i believe. Can you provide some more information of the rationale of doing this in the case of Hot Module Replacement/Webpack?

Comment: I am not at my computer(on iPhone) but I start the container(nginx with reverse proxy) with the -host parameter. And then all normal setup on host. Hope I helps. I will write later. Let me know if you get it working.

Comment: I am in fact using the dockercloud/haproxy "reverse proxy". I did set up a virtual host that is making the app available under "myapp.dev". However, Hot Module Replacement is still not working. I enable HMR through the babel-preset-react-hmre package. HMR reloading does work outside of Docker but not from within. Any thoughts, what else I could try? The problem is the virtualbox file sync issue. I still dont know how to get around it.

Comment: Ok, I never solved the sync problem. Only used the workaround solution. I will be very interested if you solve this.

Comment: I got it to work following instructions on this 
[blog post](http://andrewhfarmer.com/webpack-hmr-tutorial/).
`if (module.hot) { module.hot.accept(); }`