# Webpack dev server hot mode not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Heres my config:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: '/web/dist/',
    hot: true,
    stats: {colors: true},
    inline: true
}
```

And here's the gulp task im running:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'styles', 'bower', 'media', 'data', 'homepage'], function(done) {
    es6promise.polyfill();

    console.log('STARTING DEV SERVER...');

    server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackDevConfig), webpackDevConfig.devServer);
    server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
             throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
        }

        console.log('DEV SERVER STARTED');

        done();
    });
});
```

Everything works as expected except the hot loading (no refresh or change when I make changes to files). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` to your index.html It is not added when you use the API

"Notice that webpack configuration is not passed to WebpackDevServer API, thus devServer option in webpack configuration is not used in this case. Also, there is no inline mode for WebpackDevServer API. `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` should be inserted to HTML page manually."
(http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

maybe you also need to add `'webpack/hot/dev-server'` as an entrypoint to your webpack config

Comment: i'm seeing this in the console: [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
framework.bundle.js:114 Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.

Comment: hmm do you have `plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]` added in your webpack config?

Comment: okay that seemed to help but now it just doesn't update on changed files. [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
framework.bundle.js:600 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... change files and nothing happens

Comment: do I need to set this publicPath option? what exactly is the publicPath supposed to point to?

Comment: I don't think you need a public path for this. It should be for serving static content. Otherwise I have no idea. Maybe you can add your webpack.config to the question…

Comment: I'm also using docker and I think that's the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212372/webpack-and-react-jsx-hot-loading-not-working-with-docker-container. I'll mark this as accepted though because it does work if i trigger a change in the docker container manually.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to set

```
webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
```

in the webpackConfig as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux can try this.

For some random reason `redux-devtools` was not allowing hot reload for me. Try removing it from root component and `redux compose` config.

Note: Use redux devtool browser extension with this config in your store configuration: `window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f`

Also, must read: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpacks-hmr-react-hot-loader-the-missing-manual-232336dc0d96#.ejpsmve8f

Or try hot reload 3: 
example: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915