# Using webpack-dev-server and Hot Module Replacement not updating bundle.js with changes to JS or SCSS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using an npm script `npm start` to run `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --inline --open` in the Terminal. My React app loads up fine on the local server. But when I make any SCSS changes for example I see:

```
webpack: bundle is now INVALID.
Hash: 619812c0fa6ffc42708e
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 343ms
                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                           bundle.js    1.02 MB       0  [emitted]  main
0.065f433e5a1a691720c9.hot-update.js  659 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
065f433e5a1a691720c9.hot-update.json   36 bytes          [emitted]
chunk    {0} bundle.js, 0.065f433e5a1a691720c9.hot-update.js (main) 946 kB [rendered]
  [249] ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./src/styles/main.scss 586 bytes {0} [built]
     + 251 hidden modules
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

However, the page doesn't reflect any SCSS or JS changes I make. My bundle.js is not updated at all. However, if i run `webpack` in another Terminal window my bundle.js updates and then if I refresh my page I can see my changes.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry:  "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    path: "./build/scripts",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel",
        exclude: "./node_modules"
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ "style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap" ]
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

Here is my main.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// CSS
import "./styles/main.scss"

let docBody = "Webpack is doing its thing, with ES2015!!";
document.write(docBody);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I doubt it'll be possible to figure out what the problem is without some more information. Post the *exact console output*, your webpack config and anything else that is relevant to your code. If possible, create a small example that you can use to reproduce the problem and share the code for that.

Comment: When you load up your page, check the JavaScript console (usually F12 in your browser). Do you see the messages shown [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-module-replacement-with-inline-mode-on-cli)?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: Do you see `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` or not? If not, then the hot reload script probably hasn't loaded correctly.

Comment: No, I don't see that. How would i fix the script?

Comment: Do [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30513752/6650102) fix your problem?

Comment: No. The page now reloads but no changes are reflected. My bundle.js file is still not getting updated.